# AWS Lambda function defined in YML file fails when Role added

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created following yml file to deploy with SAM in AWS. But when I added the Role it fails with error "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE. Reason: No reason was provided.". Why does it happens?

```
Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub 'awscodestar-${ProjectId}-lambda-HelloWorld'
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Role: arn:aws:iam::790615885331:role/lambda_dynam
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: post
```

It fails if I completely remove the Role and it works only if I added following expression as the Role

```
  Role:
    Fn::GetAtt:
    - LambdaExecutionRole
    - Arn
```

I want to add a already created role.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct role name "lambda_dynam"?

Comment: Have you added the trust polity to the role?